# What is meaning of these terms "root, middle and top" in Shivastotravalli 2.9?

Tags: shiva, shivastotravali

In Shivastotravalli [Chapter 2 Hymn 9](https://archive.org/details/SahajVicharIIIShivaStotravaliOfAcharyaUtpaldevaEnglishTranslationDinanathGanjoo/page/n45), Acharya Utpaladeva says:

> Obeisance to Thee! The total benevolence The root middle and top all in one, The root, The Middle and The top individually, And one without root, middle or top.

What are these root, middle top term? What he is talking about here? Is there any better interpretation to understand this hymn?

Comment: Maybe beginning, middle, end of everything

Comment: Is Shivastotravali a stotra or a part of Tantra? Why is this tagged tantra?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Acharya Utpaladeva was from Tantric sampradaya. His all philosophy and text were for Tantra only.

Comment: But your question is not about tantra or Utpaladeva. It's about a word in a stotra. He might have written about Tantra but we should tag based on content of the question. For example we don't tag every question about Adi Shankaracharya with Advaita tag because he wrote about Advaita or he belongs to that tradition.We should follow the method as written in [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/218/5212).

Answer (score 1):

Rough transliteration :

> mulAya madhyAyAgrAya mulamadhyamurtayE
>
> kshInAgra madhya mUlAya namah pUrnAya shambhavE

I think, it is eulogisation of **Shiva or Shambhu**  in spiritual way, but not in literal way.

It is about the God, who is the beginning of everything, sustainer of everything and end of everything.

Again, it also says that the **Shambhu**, the Almighty, has no beginning, ending and continuation also, indicating that HE IS THERE AT ALL TIMES.

**purnA** indicates that the God encompasses everything.

Comment: +1 . Can be interpreted that way. But I think this is talking about bindus of essence.

Comment: May be @TheLittleNaruto